# Load external content in a div

Tags: jquery

I want the functionality using jquery/ajax where an image or java animation or external page loads in a div depending on what button is clicked.

1) On clicking the button, a new image/java animation/page replaces the previous image/animation/page in the div.

2) Some function calculates and stores the time it took for the content to download

Is this possible?

All the content is sitting on a different domain and the java animation is going to need some script. do i need to worry about the 'same origin policy'?

sorry for being vague, let me add some more details:

a) I want to avoid using iframes

b) Jquery's .load function always pulls the html content from a file. I would like to download the image from a url like: http://example.com/test/abc.jpg instead.

c) To get the animation working, I need to get it's script loaded. Is .append the only way to do that?

Comment: Yes it is possible with simple Get request (when on same domain) or a JSONP request (in case of cross domain request)

Comment: Do you *have to* load the content in a `<div>` or is an iframe a reasonable option ?

Answer (score 0):

You do have to worry about the same origin policy, unless your content can be only JSON, which it is not if I understood correctly.

Your best guess will be to use an iframe and update its target on button click. With jQuery you can do it this way :

```
<iframe src="" id="my-iframe"></iframe>
```

Then

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){
    var new_content_url = 'http://some.domain.tld/content.jpg';
    $('#my-iframe').attr('src', new_content_url);
});
```

As for the second part of your question, the `ready` event will fire on your iframe once loaded. You could do something akin to this :

```
var start = new Date();
$('#my-iframe').ready(function(){
     var stop = new Date();
     var elapsed = (stop.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000;
     console.log('loading took ' + elapsed + 'seconds.');
});
```

Comment: OP **clearly** states he wants the data loaded into a `<div>`, not an `<iframe>` element.

Comment: `<div>` is often being used as a placeholder for "any DOM element", thus my answer.

Comment: OP has clarified the non-use of `<iframe>` elements as his intention.

Comment: @Jimbo I can read english, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery 'load':

**Example Code:**

```
<style>
    #content{
        border:1px solid #000;
        padding:10px;
        height:160px;
        width:230px;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>        
    $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            var btnId = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#content").load(btnId + ".html", function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>

<button id="index">Index</button>
<button id="welcome">Welcome</button>
<button id="contact">Contact</button>

<div id="content"></div>
```

**Here is HTML files:**

1. index.html with content `'<hi>index page</hi>'`
2. welcome.html with content `'<hi>welcome page</hi>'`
3. contact.html with content `'<hi>contact page</hi>'`

and now here is

**External url load example with PHP:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            // get url from text box
            var url = $('#url').val();
            $("#content").load('process.php?url='+ url, function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value='' /><button id="load">Load URL Page</button>

<div id="content"></div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: Where is your code example specific to OP's question that will help instead of just copying / pasting from the docs?

Comment: @Jimbo: I think it's better now :)

Comment: @NeerajSingh Thanks for the solution. I am getting a 404 as xhr.status for any url. could this be my hosting provider?

Comment: the only url it works for is my own website. for everything else, i get the 404 error

Comment: @TanveerDewan: Please, share your code

Comment: @TanveerDewan: if you are getting 404 error, it means you are using url with jQuery. Try to php side function and get url content and return as ajax response.